# how to access files & folders from /(root) directory in unrooted android device

Tags: android, filesystems, root

I want to access files & folders from /(root) directory of device which is not rooted.
I have tried `Environment.getRootDirectory()` and it returns `/system` but instead of this I want to get / directory not /system.
Can anybody please tell me how to do this.